# Identify Duplicates in MySQL across columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table with name, contact1, contact2 and contact3 columns. Is there a way to find out of a given number exists in either of the 3 contact columns?

I am looking identify if a number exists more than once across contact1, contact2 and contact3 columns.

Please help.

Comment: Don't splay an array (of "contacts") across columns.  Instead, have a separate table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a query like this one:

```
SELECT contact_id, contact1, contact2, contact3
FROM contact
WHERE 
(
  (contact1 = contact2)
  OR
  (contact2 = contact3)
  OR
  (contact1 = contact3)
);
```

See the db-fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c4h4sRce7xLXv4MTJJs87v/1) (see DDL and DML below).

Result:

```
contact_id  contact1    contact2    contact3
____________________________________________
         3   phone31     phone33     phone33
```

Of course, if MySQL had `CHECK CONSTRAINT`s, this problem could be avoided at the DDL level! From [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html), you have this gem:

> CHECK
>
> The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.

============= DDL and DML ============

```
CREATE TABLE contact
(
  contact_id INTEGER,
  contact1 VARCHAR(20),
  contact2 VARCHAR(20),
  contact3 VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO contact
VALUES
(1, 'phone11', 'phone12', 'phone13'),
(2, 'phone21', 'phone22', 'phone23'),
(3, 'phone31', 'phone33', 'phone33'), -- << Duplicate number!
(4, 'phone41', 'phone42', 'phone43'),
(5, 'phone51', 'phone52', 'phone53');
```

Comment: The Query worked like a breeze. I used the following:

`code`SELECT count(*)
FROM jmjdata
WHERE 
(
  (con1 = '8108600007')
  OR
  (con2 = '8108600007')
  OR
  (con3 = '8108600007')
);`code`

So when a count is over 1 it means there is a duplicate in either of those columns. Super!

Also, on a DDL level how would I restrict them from adding a number that already exists? Or is that a PHP/Ajax question?

Comment: MariaDB 10.2 on the other hand does have [CHECK constraints](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/constraint/#check-constraints).

Comment: **Incredibly**, with MySQL, you're out of luck, even on into version 8!! You could try a real RDBMS :-) - PostgreSQL or, as suggested above, use MariaDB! On the other hand, you could enforce the constraint with a trigger - maybe your best route?